# JSON AJAX returns "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im trying to get a simple json on my ajax to asign the values to some inputs on my page, but i always get a undefined on my ajax alert

This is my JSON:

```
{"data":[{"Line_Number":10,"PO_Number":"P072592-1","Date":"9-07-17","Item_Number":"12789 - ","Size":"S","Description":"HDW- HINGE- PIANO- BLACK STAINLESS- .125 DIA.- HD SERIES","Delivery":"12-18-17","Quantity":800.0000,"Unit":"PCS","Unit_Price":0.8600,"Amount":"688"}]}
```

And this is my Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetOrder","Orders")/' + val,
    //data: { po_number: 'value' },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0].Date)
    },
    error: function () {
         alert('Some error occurred!');
    }
});
```

However i always get a Undefined on my alert and what i need is my "Date" Value
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you print out the object you’ll see what it is and that you’re missing one “data”

Comment: 1) open URL in browser tab and checkout responce result
2) console.log(data) on responce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see your data is

```
{"data":[{"Line_Number":10,"PO_Number":"P072592-1","Date":"9-07-17","Item_Number":"12789 - ","Size":"S","Description":"HDW- HINGE- PIANO- BLACK STAINLESS- .125 DIA.- HD SERIES","Delivery":"12-18-17","Quantity":800.0000,"Unit":"PCS","Unit_Price":0.8600,"Amount":"688"}]}
```

so you should try this once

```
data.data[0].Date
```

Comment: Thank you very much i dont know why i didnt saw this.. i even tried data[0].Date....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
success: function (response) {
    alert(response.data[0].Date)
},
...
```

Why? `data` is a key in your response json, so you'll receive an object (I named it response for simplicity) that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

Example  try this ->

```
      var obj = {"data":[{"Line_Number":10,"PO_Number":"P072592-1","Date":"9-07-17","Item_Number":"12789 - ","Size":"S","Description":"HDW- HINGE- PIANO- BLACK STAINLESS- .125 DIA.- HD SERIES","Delivery":"12-18-17","Quantity":800.0000,"Unit":"PCS","Unit_Price":0.8600,"Amount":"688"}]};
       alert('Line_Number ='+obj.data[0].Line_Number+', PO_Number ='+obj.data[0].PO_Number);
```